Slow Ubunto Boot Issue - NetworkManager.service
I’m experiencing a persistent problem with NetworkManager on my Ubuntu 24.04 system and I’m hoping someone here can help me troubleshoot and resolve the issue.
System Details:
OS: Ubuntu 24.04
Hardware: Dell laptop
VMware: Installed and running

Recently, I noticed that my NetworkManager service is starting very slowly. During boot, the systemd-analyze critical-chain command shows the following:
graphical.target @2min 3.332s
└─multi-user.target @2min 3.332s
└─vmware.service @2min 1.955s +1.374s
 └─network-online.target @2min 1.923s
   └─NetworkManager-wait-online.service @1min 3.852s +5.537s
     └─**NetworkManager.service @2.082s +1min 1.756s**
       └─dbus.service @1.973s +81ms
         └─basic.target @1.951s
           └─sockets.target @1.951s
             └─libvirtd-ro.socket @1.951s
               └─libvirtd.socket @1.949s +2ms
                 └─sysinit.target @1.931s
                   └─systemd-backlight@backlight:intel_backlight.service @1min 3.287s +15ms
                     └─system-systemd\x2dbacklight.slice @1.172s
                       └─system.slice @257ms
                         └─-.slice @257ms

Steps Taken:
Checked NetworkManager Configuration:
/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf has the following:
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile

[ifupdown]
managed=false

[device]
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no


Disabled a NetworkManager Dispatcher Script:
I temporarily moved /etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/99tlp-rdw-nm but it didn't resolve the issue.
Permissions for VMware Network Devices:
Ran these commands to adjust permissions, suspecting they might be causing the issue:
sudo chgrp vmware /dev/vmnet*
sudo chmod g+rw /dev/vmnet*

Has anyone encountered similar issues with NetworkManager and VMware?
Are there specific logs or configurations I should check to diagnose this further?
Im new in Linux in general , so any help would be amazing :)
